# Error GINGERBREAD cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to programmatically check the current android version and execute a piece of code if the version is higher than Gingerbread but when I try to use

> **android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD**

eclipse is showing following error

> **GINGERBREAD cannot be resolved or is not a field**

so what may be the reason for that?

Comment: Did you try cleaning your project?

Comment: which version of API did you build up your project ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to set your build target (e.g., Project > Properties > Android) to API Level 9 or higher to reference that symbol.

Nowadays, you usually want to set that build target to something fairly current (e.g., API Level 18), using Lint to point out anything that you reference that is higher than your `android:minSdkVersion`.